# NodeJs app with Express and express-session, cause Chrome "request is not finished yet", why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, redis

As the title said, i use express-session and redis deal with session. code like this:

```
app.use(session({
store: new RedisStore({
    "host": "115.28.87.181",
    "port": "6379",
    "ttl": 60 * 60 * 20,
    "pass": "",
    "db": 0,
    "prefix": "session"
}),
name: "sessionid",
secret: '8541539655',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 20
},
rolling: true,
unset: "destroy"
}));
```

it can store session and works well.

When i request a link like "http://127.0.0.1/sign/availd_id?id=tosone" make sure which id is available. Problems are coming in Chrome except firefox and safari.

My NodeJs server will response to chrome `{code: 200`, and wait for a long long time, the browser state is 'request is not finished yet', and JS is not run.

After a long long time about 2 minutes, Chrome will get the full information `{code:200}`. it looks like the browser wait for the `}`.

But the Server Log said it had responsed the whole information to browser long before. the log is this:`GET /sign/availd_id?id=tosone 200 73.555 ms`, it comes when i refresh the browser.

there is nothing with http keep-alive in my code.

Remove the code above or with firefox, problems will never been like that.

Comment: Can you update your answer with the relevant routes etc?

Comment: I only use mongodb store session instad of redis, every thing is ok.             Perhaps the http head length is wrong? I do not know why now.